# Word to describe people coming in and out of view, as in a crowd

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe looking at someone on the other side of a parade, train station or crowd, etc. with something passing between the two sides. The target is hidden and can only be seen between the gaps. All I can think of is "flickered".

> Walking away, he watched them as they ______ between the other people dancing until they completely disappeared.

Comment: It really helps if you can add an example sentence with a ________ where you want the word to go.

Comment: Walking away, he watched them as they ______ between the other people dancing until they completely disappeared.

Comment: ...as they shuffled between the other people..

Comment: With some effort, you might be able to put something together with "strobe."  Your scene is reminiscent of what people look like when illuminated off and on by a strobe light.

Comment: It feels like there should be a word for this, but it's so often expressed as *"he blended in to the crowd and disappeared"*, that I can't get beyond that!

Comment: It's that rapid disappearing and reappearing that I'm looking for. Perhaps there's a photographical expression?

Comment: That is giving me another idea -- stuttering.  Again, you'd have to put the sentence together quite carefully for this to work. // And actually I think flickering is better because it's often associated with visual phenomena.

Comment: @aparente001 how about shuttering? Might not be a real word but I keep thinking that maybe there's a photographical term

Comment: You might be able to make it work.

Comment: I have been contacted by the Macquarie Oxford dictionary and they have informed me that there is no vowel for this. Time to make a new word.

Comment: @PeterLynch I even researched 'lensing' the photo technique of discovering distant 'planets'

Comment: fade-in fade-out  ? fading in and out.

Answer (score 1):

**blink**  [freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blink)

> a glance; glimpse

As in your sentence:

> Walking away, he watched as they **blinked** in and out between the
>   other people dancing ... until they completely disappeared.

and from the book RAIN:

> They sparked everywhere in the darkness, like disconnected fireworks,
>   hovering in the air, **blinking in and out of view**. [Rain](https://books.google.com/books?id=iN3kAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT138&ots=qZC9sl3FQI&dq=%22blinking%20in%20and%20out%20of%20view%22&pg=PT138#v=onepage&q=%22blinking%20in%20and%20out%20of%20view%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Your tittle and question are inconsistent. The first is about looking through a crowd, the other is about being seen through a crowd.

Several suggestions:

Walking away, he watched them as they **reappeared** between the other people dancing until they completely disappeared.

Walking away, he watched them **through the** people dancing until they completely disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

For high-frequency appearing/disappearing, I like @aparente001 's suggestion of "strobe".

For the example with dancing, I don't imagine "them" appearing and disappearing at a frequency as high as the train station situation, but here's an alternative which I think conveys a sense of slowly appearing and disappearing as a person or persons move between people dancing:

> Walking away, he watched them as they **weaved** between the other people
>   dancing until they completely disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

How does visually "materialized" seem as a fit?

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/materialize

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a phrase that fits your example sentence exactly. I would write it like this:

> Walking away, he **caught glimpses** of them between the other people
>   dancing until they completely disappeared.